# how to solve error with downloading file by node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, download, backend

i am trying to download files from my server using node.js by res.download function from express but i got undefined error
my folder located at `D:\program\web\java_script\Node\my_project\ketabk\Books`
i need to download file from this director

that is my code i got undefined error i am sure that path is correct but i do not what is wrong !

```
let download = async (req, res) => {
  var str = req.url;
  var arr = str.split("path=");
  var value = arr.pop();
  try {
    let filePATH = path.join(__dirname + `/../Books/${value}`);
    let result = await res.download(filePATH, value, (error) => {
      console.log(`error ${error}  `);
    });
    logger.info("download one ", result);
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error("error while downloading ", error);
    console.log(error);
    res.end;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working, I did just small changes. I think the problem is in the file path, I added code to make sure the file exists

I did a request to this and downloaded normally: http://localhost:3000/?path=NiceBook.txt

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs')

let download = async (req, res) => {
  var str = req.url;
  var arr = str.split("path=");
  var value = arr.pop();
  try {
    let filePATH = path.join(__dirname + `/../Books/${value}`);

    if (!fs.existsSync(filePATH)) {
      res.send("File doest not exist");
    }

    res.download(filePATH, value, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        res.send(error);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
};

app.get('/', download)

const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
});
```